# Send same text in phone notification as entered in text_field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When a phone notification is sent,

**Expected Output:**

`[Hi there! What's up?]`

**Current Output:**

`[Hi there! What&#39s up?]`.

I need to avoid ' being converted to &#39

```
<%= f.text_field :notification, :class => "charcounter form-control", :data => {:allowed => FeedbackReply::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, :warning => 30} %>
```

Comment: Can you please provide what it output right now?

Comment: Try reverse `
@message = "Hi there! What&#39s up?"` see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x9sjysas/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

I think there is a special character's issue in this case you don't need of `html_safe` but you need to use **[sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize)**

This `sanitize` helper will html encode all tags and strip all attributes that aren't specifically allowed.

---

I'm not sure but you can try this:

```
<%= @yourobject.notification.html_safe %>
```

**Note:**  `html_safe` actually "sets the string" as HTML Safe (it's a little more complicated than that, but it's basically it). This way, you can return HTML Safe strings from helpers or models at will. Don't use html_safe unless you’re sure your string isn’t `nil`. It will send exception if string returns `nil`

`html_safe` does **not** HTML-escape your string. In fact, it will prevent your string from being escaped.

**Example:**

```
<%= "<script>alert('Hello!')</script>" %>
```

will output:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#x27;Hello!&#x27;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

into your HTML source (yay, so safe!), while:

```
<%= "<script>alert('Hello!')</script>".html_safe %>
```

will pop up the alert dialog (are you sure that's what you want?).

"**[SafeBuffers and Rails 3.0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)**" is a nice explanation on how the SafeBuffers (the class that does the html_safe magic) work.

Comment: Sure. But it says undefined local variable or method `notification'

Comment: Which object you are using to pass parameter? for eg: if you are using `@posts` then try  `<%= @posts.notification.html_safe %>`

Comment: It can be nil in this case.

Comment: What you wanted actually? what is your purpose? there may be other options available..